# Font kerning (horizontal space between characters) in matplotlib superscript in suptitle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this snippet:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
mynumber = 0
fig.suptitle(r'Yeah, this: $\mathregular{{2^{{ {}+1 }} }}$'.format(mynumber), fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

On Matplotlib 3.1.1, Python 3.7.5 under MINGW64 (MSYS2) in Windows 10, I get this for the plot title:

[image: fig_suptitle]

However, for my taste, the horizontal white space/kerning between the `0` and the `+` (and, between the `+` and the `1`) in the `0 + 1` text, is a bit too much; I would like a tighter kerning, something like this (photo edited in Gimp):

[image: fig_suptitle_02]

Is this possible to do/control in Matplotlib, and if so - how can I control this (the kerning in superscript in plot title text, with default font)?

Comment: Would `$\mathregular{{2^{{ {}\!+\!1 }} }}$` be enough?

Comment: Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - using `\!` is better (tighter kerning), but I'd prefer it even tighter than that, if possible ...

Comment: `$\mathregular{{2^{{ {}\!\!+\!\!1 }} }}$` maybe?

Comment: Exactly, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - just found what the command means, doubled it, and got what I wanted - and posted an answer about it below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Again, thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest -> the `\!` is actually a TeX command, and it means:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455375/what-does-aka-backslash-exclamation-mark-do

> The command `\!` is only allowed in math mode ...
>   It's purpose is to insert a negative thin space, which is useful in several places ...
>   The negative spacing of `\!` exactly matches the positive one by `\,`

... and so, it turns out, it can be "stacked", that is, repeated, for even more tightening; and I just had to repeat it twice, to get almost the same output as the one I photo-shopped in the OP:

```
fig.suptitle(r'Yeah, this: $\mathregular{{2^{{ {}\!\!+\!\!1 }} }}$'.format(mynumber), fontsize=14)
```

So, this is good, now ...